# Сортировка значений внутри поля с поиском товаров woocommerce(анaлогичного crossell)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Создаю произвольное поле в админке Woocommerce "Выбор товаров с поиском" поле аналогично выбору кроссел и апсел.

```
?>
<p class="form-field product_field_type">
   <label for="product_field_type">Выбор товаров</label> <select 
id="product_field_type"
  name="product_field_type[]" class="wc-product-search" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%;" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search for a product&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" data-action="woocommerce_json_search_products_and_variations" data-exclude="<?php echo intval( $post->ID ); ?>">
  <?php
  $product_field_type_ids = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_product_field_type_ids', true );
  $product_ids = ! empty( $product_field_type_ids ) && isset($product_field_type_ids) ? array_map( 'absint',  $product_field_type_ids ) : array();
  if ( $product_ids ) {
     foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product      = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $product_name = $product->get_formatted_name();
        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $product_id ) . '" ' . selected(true, true, false )  . '>' .
             esc_html( $product->get_formatted_name() ) . '</option>';
     }
  }
  ?>
```

При заполнении этого поля-списка, товары после выбора сортируются по имени, впрочем так происходит и в стандартных полях кроссел и апсел.

Как сделать чтобы выбранные товары оставались в том порядке в каком их выбирали?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить к тегу select значение data-sortable="true"

Comment: Эм.. Точно true?

Comment: у меня сработало, сделал по аналогии с сгруппированными продуктами